# Is there a way to get WebGL to render offscreen, without the webgl canvas attached to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webgl

I thought this would be an easy question to find an answer for, but it's turning out to be very elusive. Basically, I'm trying to use WebGL to do the heavy lifting on some image processing and generation tasks, and I want it to work offscreen. Ideally, I'd like WebGL to render a scene to a framebuffer that I can `gl.readPixels()` from, or to the webgl canvas so I can use it as a *source* for `context.drawImage()`. The thing is, I don't want to display the webgl canvas itself, I only want to copy portions of it to a visible canvas that I have a regular "2d" context for. So far, I can't seem to get it to work without the following initialization, which seems like an ugly hack to me:

```
glCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
glCanvas.width = 256;
glCanvas.height = 256;
document.body.appendChild(glCanvas); // seems necessary, but why?
glCanvas.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // ugh, is this the only way?
```

Currently, I'm rendering a scene to a framebuffer I create with:`gl.createFramebuffer()`, using a single `gl.drawArrays()` call, and then using `gl.readPixels()` to get the result out to an ImageData. With the glCanvas attached to the DOM it works exactly as planned. But if I leave off those last 2 lines of code above where I attach the glCanvas and hide it, I get no image when I try to readPixels from the framebuffer I've rendered to.

I don't understand why the glCanvas needs to be attached to the DOM, if it's not even being rendered to. I thought that rendering to a framebuffer happens entirely on the graphics card and that the buffer will persist for me to use as a texture. Is it simply the case that WebGL doesn't render at all unless there is at least one webgl-context canvas attached to the DOM? Or am I missing some other detail? Thanks!

Comment: This may help although not entirely mature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas

Comment: @K3N I came across that, and it looks promising for future use. But as you say, not ready for prime time. It looks to be implemented only in Firefox, and  really just for developers to get early access to via an about:config setting.

Comment: @Blindman67 :-/ Your suggestions are good, but had you actually read past the title of my post, you'd know that I'm already rendering to framebuffers and hiding my gl canvas. I'm asking if there is a proper, best-practices way to render offscreen without crude hacks like hidden layers or 1 pixel canvases.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you for clarifying. That is disappointing indeed, and a bit surprising considering how heavily WebGL is being used now. I do hope it continues to be supported, though I've given up the dream of getting WebCL :-(

Comment: The web will, by virtue of its multi platform nature, be for some time to come a cutdown of what can be done. Valkan is the new 3D open standard, so keep your fingers crossed that WebGL is not forgotten, or maybe back to the glory days when MS set the standard and IE4-5 kicked ass. DX12 for a browser anyone??? DirectX has always had the best goods to play with.

Comment: Weirdly, setting my gl canvas to width and height of 0 also works, though the drawingBufferWidth and drawingBufferHeight still report as 1, it does not render a single pixel to the page.

Comment: @LJᛃ My bad, I should have said OpenGL ES  2.0 a decade old hack to run on the most basic system and completely outdated.

Comment: @Blindman67 "a decade old hack to run on the most basic system". It's exactly why ES2 has been chosen for the web. It can run everywhere...

Comment: @pleup No it can not run everywhere. If you consider the fact that most 3D apps require not only a minimum feature set, but also a minimum throughput. There are many examples of webGL that struggle on just average machines, and we are still left to guess whether an app will run. So why limit the API. To be a useful API it should allow full use of a devices capabilities and let us programer decide what we want from a device. As consumers we have every right to demand better, WebGL is a hack and we should insist on only the best, not quietly accept outdated kludges.

Comment: After trying gman's example below with readPixels, and seeing it work fine, I went on a hunt for cause of my woes. Turned out to be some web template include js files on our site trying to handle resizing of a canvas named "gl" (used all over the place for webgl canvas contexts that are always intentionally visible). It was doing bad things to my unattached canvas due to its clientWidth and clientHeight being zero, among other things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to have the canvas in the DOM to use WebGL. There's plenty of tests in the [WebGL Conformance Tests](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html) that run without ever adding a canvas to the DOM

```js
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
gl.clearColor(1,0,1,1); // purple;
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// draw in 2d canvas
var ctx = document.querySelector("#c2d").getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(gl.canvas, 10, 20, 30, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="c2d"></canvas>
```

Maybe you should post some more code. You probably have some other bug.

---

### Update

Coming soon is also the [`OffscreenCanvas API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas). As of 2017/11/15 It's available in both Firefox and Chrome behind a flag. It allows using WebGL in a Web Worker

### Update 2

As of Chrome 69 OffscreenCanvas is shipping without a flag.

Comment: I found the bug. There is a utility script that is imported on all pages of our site that puts in some boilerplate stuff. One of the things it does is try to handle smartly resizing things on the page. I stupidly called my offscreen canvas context "gl", the same as visible webgl canvases on other pages of the site. I didn't notice the resize script did this: `var width  = gl.canvas.clientWidth;
 var height = gl.canvas.clientHeight;
 if (gl.canvas.width !== width ||  gl.canvas.height !== height)
 {
  gl.canvas.width  = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;
    }` So yeah, 0px by 0px, doh!

Comment: Simply renaming the variable holding the reference to my unattached webgl canvas fixed this issue. That's actually not the only thing that the common code includes were doing assuming possible existence of a "gl" variable. Lesson learned: know what you're importing, even if it's old code that predates you and causes no known issues anywhere else on a large website.

Comment: What if I want to draw to a canvas which has a WebGL context (as opposed to a 2d context)? Can this be done?

Comment: Also, please note that I'm aware that OffScreenCanvas API exists, however this is not supported by Safari & my solution requires Safari support.

Comment: That example is in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use an OffScreenCanvas.

You can learn more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/offscreen-canvas/).

You should do something like this:

```js
const offscreen = document.querySelector('canvas').transferControlToOffscreen();
const worker = new Worker('myworkerurl.js');
worker.postMessage({canvas: offscreen}, [offscreen]);
```